# IWAB0135E An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I have this error when I'm trying to invoke an operation of my web service. I'm using Eclipse and the web service is a simple "Say hello" one. Here's the entire error :

```
IWAB0135E An unexpected error has occurred.
java.net.ConnectException
Connection timed out: connect
```

Does anyone know how I could fix that ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It says "java.net.ConnectException Connection timed out: connect". Make sure that your end points are correct and service is listening properly.